# Please destroy the [mechanicaldream] -> [mechanical-dream] tag synonym

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

We have a [a tag synonym](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) pointing [mechanicaldream](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanicaldream) to [mechanical-dream](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-dream), and it's preventing me from *actually* recreating the [mechanical-dream](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mechanical-dream) tag and reapplying it to one of our past questions that lost its system tag. Could this tag synonym be destroyed?

Nowadays, SE has protection from creating [thistag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thistag) if [this-tag](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/this-tag) already exists, so this tag synonym is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go, boss. Synonym nuked (apparently it was never used).